# Cannot copy files in recovery mode which made Google nexus S unusable

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, custom-roms, recovery-mode, file-management

I have a Google Nexus S, bought last year and it was working fine till last week. It came with Android Ginger Bread, and I rooted the phone and installed several custom ROMs including Cyanogenmod. Recently I installed Android Jelly bean ROM, and it was working fine.

Last week, I wanted to try the Cyanogedmod 10 (on Jelly bean). I went to recovery mode for taking a backup. But I saw a recent backup which was taken before 2 months. I thought that should be fine. I cleared all cache and did a factory reset for getting ready for the new ROM.

Now something went wrong!

I tried to reboot the device, but I could only see the usual animated CROSS logo( with four colours) for ever. I even left the phone for more than a hour. But it is not rebooting. //SO CAN'T RELOAD THE PREVIOUSLY WORKING OS

I tried restoring from the previous backup.. It shows that "installation complete".
After that while rebooting the device just hangs in the same place. //SO CAN'T RESTORE FROM MY PREVIOUS BACKUP

I thought of copying the new rom in the device. I could not succeed. I tried adb command through my SDK.
ADB is not listing my device. In all the forums it is mentioned that to enable the USB debugging from the phone.
I cannot do this, because I cannot go into the device OS other than recovery mode.

I even tried some GUI stuff like Android commander / QtADB but every thing needs USB Enable from the OS Menu.

Finally I tried mounting disk from recovery mode.
Whenever I mount the disk, Windows 7 is fixing the file system errors and bad sectors for a while and shows "no problems were found" and it is ready to use. Here something weird happens. I can copy the files in windows explorer and can see the files in the device thru explorer,

BUT when I unmount and browse from the recovery mode the files are not there. (may be the files are copied in cache) //SO I CAN'T COPY ANY FILE TO THE DEVICE.. ( May be here I am doing something silly. )

My phone is now unusable!

Any advice/tips is highly appreciated!

Cheers Kum

Answer (score 3):

Prerequesites:

- unlocked phone ('fastboot oem unlock' command)
- installed Android SDK with accessible adb and fastboot executables (both are part of the SDK)
- Cyanogenmod 7/9 or 10 image from [get.cm](http://get.cm/?device=crespo) (or whatever ROM you want)
- Nexus S CWM recovery image from [clockworkmod.com](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager/)

Steps:

1. Flash the CWM recovery image:
   Switch off your Nexus S, press **volume up & power** to enter fastboot mode
   Command to flash: `fastboot flash recovery recovery-clockwork-6.0.1.0-crespo.img`
2. Boot to recovery (e.g. via `fastboot boot recovery-clockwork-6.0.1.0-crespo.img`)
3. Enter a shell into the running CWM: `adb shell`, from there mount a tmpfs file system (used just for the update): `mount -t tmpfs none /sdcard` (This circumvents the sdcard completely, you don't need to format anything)
4. Push the ROM image to the tmpfs (`adb push cm-10-20120827-NIGHTLY-crespo.zip /sdcard/`)
5. Install this via CWM (the regular way)
6. Follow the remaining [usual steps](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Nexus_S%3a_Full_Update_Guide) (GApps, wipe, etc.)

Comment: Hi @ce4  
Thank you for the quick response.  
All prerequisites are ready and in place.  
As per Step 1, I entered in to fastboot mode  
(with Lock State - UNLOCKED which is fine..)  
The command  
`fastboot flash recovery recovery-clockwork-6.0.1.0-crespo.img`  
shows  
`< waiting for device >`  
`adb devices` didn't show any device.
I selected `recovery` from fastboot mode,  
`List of devices attached  
 3530CF39E0F800EC        recovery`  
Still it is waiting for device.  
Am I doing any thing wrong here?  

Thanks in advance  
Kumaran

Comment: Finally I bypassed Step 1 and 2 and tried Step 3
I was happy during this step, because the pushed file was visible 
in the recovery mode.
Then I installed it and rebooted..

Now it is hanging with Google logo and unlock image. 
(Previous to the Colourful CROSS image)

Comment: Bypassing step1+2 will not work, the incl. recovery doesn't allow flashing I think. *fastboot* and *adb* need access rights to the phone via USB (start either as root or [add some udev rules](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)). You then can flash the CWM recovery image. You should see something like [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/26362/15713)). [This post](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/28363/15713) shows the output of both unlock and flash commands (for the Nexus 7 here). Just ask again if you need more help and please share your findings once you're done :-)

Comment: Hi @ce4  
Initially I tried in Windows 7.  
Today I used Ubuntu for ensuring root access.
Then I followed these steps and installed the zip and wiped dalvik, cache etc. One thing I did was, I reinstalled the same zip again..(because wasn't sure about the order of wipe and install) and rebooted. This stage I was very happy..

But again it strucks in the same place..
Any advice?

Comment: Any progress since your last status report? We'd better meet in chat maybe...

Comment: Hi @ce4.. No progress after that, I tried several ways but still it is in bricked state. I would definitely like to chat. Let me know your convenient time.

Comment: argh, forgot the 20 rep limit you need for chat. Can you state which step you are in? And what failed?

Comment: Hi @ce4 Still my mobile is in bricked mode. Is there any chance, I can chat with you to get help from you. I am reachable in kumaran<dot>masilamani<at>gmail<dot>com