# Flash Nexus 7 without USB Debugging

Tags: rom-flashing, bootloader, usb-debugging

My Nexus 7 32gb WiFi, running stock 4.2.1, is stuck on the Nexus 'X' symbol loading screen after boot. It stays there until the battery goes flat. The issue is that I have not enabled developer or debugging mode, meaning that I cannot connect to the PC via the adb.

Is there another way that I can flash a new ROM? Apologies if this is a question answered elsewhere, but all recovery methods that I have discovered so far require 'USB Debugging', which I currently do not have access to.

Comment: You don't need usb debugging to flash. You need to unlock the bootloader and boot in to the recovery.

Comment: But how does one unlock the bootloader without having USB debugging enabled?

Comment: Related: [Nexus 7 stuck in a boot loop](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28361/nexus-7-stuck-in-a-boot-loop/28363#28363) - a boot loop is you seeing the "X" forever.

Comment: All you need to is boot to the bootloader by holding the Power button and Vol Down at the same time for a while.