# Is it possible to recover files from Nexus 5 stuck in boot loop?

Tags: nexus-5, boot-loop

I have a Nexus 5 that starts up, says "Optimizing apps" and then reboots and repeats this endlessly. I just want to recover my files from the phone. Is there any way to accomplish this through Recovery mode, maybe by mounting the data folder? The only option I have for mounting is "Mount /system" but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Guess the same procedure as for a [Nexus 7 stuck in a boot loop](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28361/16575) should apply?

Comment: @Izzy it says in the answer that it wipes the data, so I don't think that will help me

Comment: It says it wipes data *if you not yet have unlocked your bootloader.* Have you?